# Elasticsearch doesn't find all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm using rails 5.0.0.1, elasticsearch-model, elasticsearch-rails and the search for some records works correctly for whole word and for partial but for other records not works totally. ES version 2.3.1.
My location.rb:

```html
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base   
  include Elasticsearch::Model   
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

      settings analysis: {   filter: {
        ngram_filter: { type: "nGram", min_gram: 2, max_gram: 12 }   },   analyzer: {
            index_ngram_analyzer: {
                type: 'custom',
                tokenizer: 'standard',
                filter: ['lowercase', 'ngram_filter']
            },
            search_ngram_analyzer: {
                type: 'custom',
                tokenizer: 'standard',
                filter: ['lowercase']
            }
        }   } do
        mapping do
            indexes :location, :type => "string", analyzer:   "index_ngram_analyzer", search_analyzer: "search_ngram_analyzer"
            indexes :address, :type => "string", analyzer:   "index_ngram_analyzer", search_analyzer: "search_ngram_analyzer"
        end
      end
```

http://localhost:9200/locations/_count return {"count":12463,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}, it means that all locations are indexed.

Please, help - what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please provide your query as well, for which you feel it isn't displaying the required results

Comment: Archit Saxena- Its not the right place to ask but just wanted to know is there any vacancy in your company regarding ruby on rails?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/search?query=soft find all locations where name is "softengi", but http://localhost:3000/search?query=wal and http://localhost:3000/search?query=walmart doesn't return location where name "walmart"(( Now in company, where I'm working no RoR vacancies((